# Automate data purging from RDS postgresql instance in AzureDevops Pipeline

Tags: postgresql, azure-pipelines, amazon-rds, purge

I'm looking for pipeline setup to purge data from RDS PostgreSQL instance using AzureDevOps pipeline. If anyone can share the idea or steps it would be very helpful.